# Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить код на базе функций if - else, чтобы при вводе 21 выводилось "...21 года"

Tags: python, if

```
age = input("Укажите свой возраст: ")
```

Если последний численный элемент строки "age" не равняется "1"

```
if age[-1] != int(1):     

    print('Как здорово, что ты дожил до ' + age + " лет")

else:

    print('Как здорово, что ты дожил до ' + age + " года")
```

Cейчас этот код при вводе 21 упрямо выводит:

> как здорово, что ты дожил до 21 лет

Comment: *Если последний численный элемент строки "age" не равняется "1"* Какой тип у `"1"`? а у `int(1)`? PS. Блин, я тут с вами, глядишь, и питон освою...

Comment: Понял в чем несоответствие, спасибо

Comment: Как здорово, что ты дожил до 11 года.

Comment: @Эникейщик, если прочитать не "одиннадцать", а "одиннадцатого", то звучит вполне нормально. Только такое показывать надо в 10 лет, а не в 11.

Answer (score 1):

```
if int(age) % 10 != 1 and int(age) % 100 != 11:
```

Хотя лучше бы возраст числом сохранить в переменную.

Comment: не могли бы вы подсказать, что вписать в конце кода, чтобы после выдачи результата он снова возвращался к полю ввода? Или для этого нужно обращать функцию в цикл?

Comment: Ну наверное в цикл...

Answer (score 1):

```
if age[-1] != '1' and (len(age) == 1 or age[-2] != '1'):
```

Comment: указанный мной код справился с задачей после замены int(1) на str(1)  ваше предложение тоже освою, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

```
if int(age) == 21:     

    print('Как здорово, что ты дожил до ' + age + " года")

else:

    print('Как здорово, что ты дожил до ' + age + " лет")
```

Comment: Ну и что это? Просили же "21 года", а не "21 лет". А там ещё 31 есть и дальше.

Comment: мне хотелось иметь работоспособный код и для вариаций с 31/34/41 и т.п.  "Годиков" - это четко)